# Why can't a class instance variable be accessed in a singleton-class definition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton, class-instance-variables

```
class MyClass
  @my_class_instance_variable = "here"

  p @my_class_instance_variable # => "here"

  class << self
    p @my_class_instance_variable # => nil
  end
end

class MyClass
  p @my_class_instance_variable # => "here"
end
```

Why does the second `p` print `nil`, when the third `p` prints `"here"`? My understanding of a singleton class definition (`class << self`) is that it has the same scope as a class definition (`class MyClass`).

(This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305470/why-cant-i-use-a-class-instance-variable-inside-a-singleton-class-definition) has a similar title, but it has a different focus.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding of a singleton class definition (class << self) is
>   that it has the same scope as a class definition

Nope. The scope is different. You defined `@my_class_instance_variable` in the scope of `MyClass`, but are trying to access it in the scope if `MyClass`'s singleton class.

It is as easy to check as:

```
class Foo
  puts self #=> Foo

  class << self
    puts self #=> #<Class:Foo>
  end
end
```

With the output of:

```
Foo
#<Class:Foo>
```

Comment: The singleton class - yes! Thanks a lot!